# format tibble in a specific format shown

Tags: r, tibble

I have an output table as tibble. Below is the example -

```
library(tidyverse)

Var <- c("Constant_A", "Constant_B", "Cost_A", "Cost_B")
Param <- c(2, 0, 1, 0)
tstat <- c(5, NA, 4, NA)

tbl <- tibble(Var, Param, t_stat)
```

1. I wish to format it in specific way as shown in screenshot below
2. How do I copy the table to my word document.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

In R, objects inheriting from class `"data.frame"` such as `tibbles` can only have one header. The following will pivot the data to the format in the question.

```
tbl %>%
  separate(Var, c("Var", "What")) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = Var,
    names_from = What,
    names_glue = "{What}_{.value}",
    values_from = c(Param, tstat)
  ) %>%
  select(Var, starts_with('A'), starts_with('B'))
## A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Var      A_Param A_tstat B_Param B_tstat
#  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 Constant       2       5       0      NA
#2 Cost           1       4       0      NA
```